# Open a new Safari Window on MacOS with AppleScript without messing things up

Tags: macos, safari, applescript

I tried to write a small AppleScript which will open a new Safari Window. This window should show a specific URL and shall be opened in a given size.

The additional constraints are:

1. It shall not open an additional window.
2. It shall not mess with Safari's settings by leaving my given size behind, making all new windows be that size.

What I've come up with is this:

```
-- Explanations in Comments.
on run
    tell application "Safari"
        set myURL to "https://…long url for The Moth FM…"
        activate
        -- activate will open a new empty window when Safari is not running.
        -- It will bring any other window to the front when it's running.
        try
            set oldBounds to bounds of front window
            -- I try to remember the bounds of the (new) window.
            if "favorites://" = (URL of document of front window) then
                -- if the window was an empty one, it was most probably a new window.
                close front window
                -- try to close it.
            end if
        on error errStr number errNum
            -- all the above might fail.
            -- So we do not know the original window size at the moment.
            make new document with properties {URL:"favorites://"}
            -- I open a brand new window,
            set oldBounds to bounds of front window
            -- so that I get the bounds of new windows.
            close front window
            -- Then I directly close it again.
        end try
        -- All the above is just preparation to rememver Safari's
        -- default Window size (and position).
        make new document with properties {URL:myURL}
        -- Now I create the window I want
        set bounds of front window to {21, 46, 621, 191}
        -- and set its size.
        -- This size has now become Safari's new default size. :(
        make new document with properties {URL:"favorites://"}
        -- So I create another window
        set bounds of front window to oldBounds
        -- and set its size to the default size retrieved above
        close front window
        -- and close it, as I don't need it.
    end tell
end run
```

This seems a bit cumbersome and maybe someone here has an idea how to do this more smoothly without all the window-"flickery"?

Comment: Might it be simpler to check if Safari has a window(or running) vs when it has none?  That's how I implemented my `newTab`. I would also use handlers, to help with the readibility.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @user3579815. Can you please show me how to reliably do that? All my attempts were very unreliable. Nevertheless I still would need to open and close a window with the old dimensions to not make my small window the new standard, right?

Comment: I gave this a try, launching a new window, then launching a temporary window, and resizing it to the desired dimension doesn't make the new windows take the preferred size. There must be a better way to solve your requirement. One thing I use to manage my windows is Magnet app. For the customization, I use AppleScript to resize and position the windows where I want them to be. I never rely on the default sizing anymore and when I did, it was annoying :D

Comment: @user3579815 try this: Start Safari. Resize the window. Close Safari. Open Safari. The new window should have your resized dimensions. Now try this: Start Safari. Resize the window. Open a new window. Resize to default size you want. Close that window. Close Safari. Open Safari. The new window should have your new default dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I played around with, based on your last comment. Feel free to update to your needs, not really a proper answer but I hope it helps you accomplish your goal, good luck!

```
global DEFAULT_BOUNDS, CUSTOM_BOUNDS
-- set DEFAULT_BOUNDS to {x:missing value, y:missing value, w:missing value, h:missing value}
 set DEFAULT_BOUNDS to {x:210, y:146, w:621, h:491}
set CUSTOM_BOUNDS to {x:21, y:46, w:621, h:191}

-- part1() -- un/commen as needed
part2() -- un/comment as needed
```

1. Start Safari.
2. Resize the window.
3. Close Safari.
4. Open Safari.

The new window should have your resized dimensions.

```
to part1()
    activate application "Safari"
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari" to set theWindow to first window
    resize(theWindow, CUSTOM_BOUNDS)
    tell application "Safari" to quit
    repeat while running of application "Safari" is true
        delay 1
    end repeat
    activate application "Safari"
end part1
```

Now try this:

1. Start Safari.
2. Resize the window.
3. Open a new window.
4. Resize to default size you want.
5. Close that window.
6. Close Safari.
7. Open Safari.

The new window should have your new default dimensions.

```
to part2()
    set theFirstWindow to newSafariWindow("https://www.example.com")
    resize(theFirstWindow, CUSTOM_BOUNDS)
    set theNewWindow to newSafariWindow("https://www.yahoo.com")
    resize(theNewWindow, DEFAULT_BOUNDS)

    tell application "Safari" to close first window
    tell application "Safari" to quit
    repeat while running of application "Safari" is true
        delay 1
    end repeat

    activate application "Safari"
end part2
```

Some auxilliary handlers

```
on saveCurrentBounds(referenceWindow)
    tell application "System Events"
        set thePosition to position of referenceWindow
    
        set x of DEFAULT_BOUNDS to first item of thePosition
        set y of DEFAULT_BOUNDS to second item of thePosition
        set theSize to size of referenceWindow
    
        set w of DEFAULT_BOUNDS to first item of theSize
        set h of DEFAULT_BOUNDS to second item of theSize
    end tell
end saveCurrentBounds

on newSafariWindow(theUrl as text)
    if running of application "Safari" is false then
        do shell script ("open -a Safari " & theUrl)
    
        script WindowWaiter
            if (count of (windows of application "Safari")) is not 0 then return true
        end script
        wait on WindowWaiter
    else
        tell application "Safari" to make new document with properties {URL:theUrl}
    end if
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari" to     return front window
end newSafariWindow

to resize(theWindow, newBounds)
    tell application "System Events"
        set position of the theWindow to {x of newBounds, y of newBounds}
        set size of the theWindow to {w of newBounds, h of newBounds}
    end tell
 end resize


to wait on scriptObj by sleep : 1 for ntimes : 1000
    repeat ntimes times
        try
            set handlerResult to run of scriptObj
            if handlerResult is not missing value then return handlerResult
        end try
        delay sleep
    end repeat
    return missing value
end exec
```

Comment: Thanks, but the comment I gave was for you to see that the resize - close stuff in fact influences the size of newly opened windows. But I saw tricks in your code which look very useful. So a big Thank You for that.